# C++: Why isn't my hash function for the unordered_map<char*, vector<int>> working?

Tags: c++, hash, unordered-map, hash-function

I want to create an unordered_map which has a `char*` as a key and a `vector<int>` as a `value`. I learned from previous questions that no hash function for `char*`  is provided by the STL.

I took the first implementation from this site: http://www.cse.yorku.ca/~oz/hash.html

So having my `main.cpp` file I inserted the following code:

```
namespace std
{
   template<>
   struct hash<char*>: public std::unary_function<char *, size_t>
   {
      size_t operator()(char * str) const{
      size_t hash = 5381;
      int c;

      while(c = *str++)
        hash = ((hash << 5) + hash) + c; /* hash * 33 + c */

      return hash;

     }
  };
}
```

Then I created an unordered_map variable:

```
std::unordered_map<char *, vector<int>> test;
```

However if I insert the value "temp" twice by doing this:

```
std::unordered_map<char *, vector<int>> test;
char *t1 = new char[5];
strcpy(t1, "temp");
char *t2 = new char[5];
strcpy(t2, "temp");
vector<int>& ptr = test[t1];
ptr.push_back(0);
vector<int>& ptr2 = test[t2];
ptr2.push_back(1);
```

the final map instead of having one "temp" key with a vector of size two where each element of the vector is either 0 or 1 it has two keys with the name "temp" and in each key a vector of size 1.

here is detailed picture:
[image]

how can I avoid this from happening? thank you in advance

Comment: Why not use `std::string`? Your hash table will leak memory.

Comment: for some reason using std::string gave me very slow execution times

I would like to see if anything would change by using char* although I have a feeling that nothing will change...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a problem with the hashing function, it's a problem with the equality of the `char*`'s.  You're relying upon pointer comparison, and you can see from the debugger watch variables, the pointers of the various "temp" literals have different locations, and are thus not equal.

You need to define an equality functor that actually does the string compare, and use that with the `unordered_map`.

Or, instead of using `char*` as your key, use `std::string`, and avoid this issue altogether.

Comment: thank you, however if we are talking about performance, wouldn't using a string give bad execution times compared to char * due to the constructor/destructor?

Comment: @ksm001: Hash tables performance will depend on the mix of insertion, collisions, retrievals, and removals. The usual assumption is that retrievals vastly outnumber removals. Your implementation is cheating anyway, since you never free your memory.